# Foreach loop is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and it does not insert the values in the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
while ($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($doquery2))
{
    $user_id = $rij['id'];
}

$cat = $_POST['cat'];

foreach($cat as $key => $value) 
{
    //$sql = "";

    if ($value > 0) 
    {
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO cat VALUES('','$user_id','%s');",$value);
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

In my form each checkbox is built as follow:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="Lifestyle">
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: note if the checkbox isn't checked, it will not submit at all.

Comment: man, do some debugging... `print_r($_POST['cat']);`. `echo $sql;` check the return value of the `mysql_query` call. I think that answers your question.

Comment: You don't `mysql_real_escape_string()` your `$user_id` and your `$value` - that's bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, an unchecked value won't get passed through to $_POST at all. So you can just strip the lines checking $value. I think you might be running into issues there with different browsers sending different values for a checked box. So try this:

```
foreach($cat as $key => $value) 
{
    //$sql = "";

    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO cat VALUES('','$user_id','%s');",$value);
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I used the exact code before and it was working then, so I don't know what caused the problem. It worked anyway, so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! It's a new problem I've been noticing and totally broke several of my sites recently, so I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

You should log your sql statement and log any mysql_error().

Also your array will be a regular index based array so you should use (although this is probably not your source of error)

```
foreach($cat as $value)
```

Comment: foreach looks nicer that way, if you don't use the key.. but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you converting $_REQUEST['cat']/$_GET['cat']/$_POST['cat'] into $cat... You seem to be looping on an array called $cat but i think you are used to work with register_globals and your server doesn't support it anymore. Thats why it's not doing what you expect.

But i might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot include table columns also `;` not required here

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO cat (id, user,category) VALUES('','$user_id','%s')",$value);
```

Comment: That should be no problem - if they are not given, MySQL will assume "all fiels in table order".

Comment: mysql can live without table fields (although it's bad practice)

Comment: Maybe but i don't think he uses all columns here and '' value is suspicious too